# SQL query not return duplicate values

Tags: mysql

i'm a beginner in mysql, so excuse me if i ask obvious questions to you. I have a table with 2 equal values, and from these values ​​I have to retrieve a series of information and show it. The problem is that when I go to print it only shows them once.

`SELECT pda, acaso, cial from giocatori where pda in (255,255,13,13)`

the result is this.

| pda | acaso | cial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 255 | 988 | 344 |
| 13 | 921 | 333 |

instead I need a result similar to this

| pda | acaso | cial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 255 | 988 | 344 |
| 255 | 988 | 344 |
| 13 | 921 | 333 |
| 13 | 921 | 333 |

thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Convert the criteria list to rowset (subquery) and use as data source.

Comment: @akina 
I don't think I know how to do it, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT pda, giocatori.acaso, giocatori.cial 
FROM giocatori 
JOIN ( SELECT 255 pda UNION ALL
       SELECT 255     UNION ALL
       SELECT 13      UNION ALL
       SELECT 13 ) criteria USING (pda)
```